# "an exciting checkmate of Ron's" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

> ... and she sat down to watch their chess match, which culminated in **an exciting checkmate of Ron's**, involving a couple of recklessly brave pawns and a very violent bishop.

'Checkmate' means:

> In chess, checkmate is a situation in which you cannot stop your king being captured and so you lose the game.

I'm wondering who really wins the game by "*an exciting checkmate of Ron's*", Ron or Harry? Is it also ok to put: "*Ron's exciting checkmate*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A checkmate is a noun but it can also be a verb, something you do to someone. It is not a very common way of saying this but often used in books to keep the action rolling.

So although the sentence is quite ambiguous I'd read it as:

> "which culminated in an exciting checkmate that Ron (inflicted on his opponent), involving a couple of recklessly brave pawns and a very violent bishop.

But yes, your version is also good and less ambiguous. I think JK went with her version because the sentence just rolls a bit better.

Comment: But note, in context there's no danger of ambiguity because we know already that Ron is a much better chess player than Harry.

Comment: still ambiguous as being a better player doesn't mean bold and reckless strategy won't get you checkmated.